# Different sort order for odoo m2m field

Tags: odoo, odoo-8

Is there any way to change the default sort order of a Many2may field?
I would like to display the most recent data at the first place.
Here is the model definition:

```
...
attachment_ids = fields.Many2many('ir.attachment', 'hr_ir_attachments_rel', 'employee_id', 'attachment_id', 'Files')
...
```

and here is the view:

```
...
<field name="attachment_ids" widget="many2many_binary" readonly='1'/>
...
```

Comment: try default_order  https://www.odoo.com/documentation/8.0/reference/views.html#reference-views-kanban  https://www.odoo.com/documentation/8.0/reference/views.html#lists

Comment: I'm afraid, there is no default_order property on fields just on tree and kanban view

Comment: you can define a many2many field as a tree view.
<field name="attachment_ids" widget="many2many_binary" readonly='1'>
<tree>
<field name="field_from_attachment_here"/>
</tree>
</field>

Comment: @programme: Well it doesn't seem to work. Actually nothing was changed compared to the initial code. What I have tried based on you code is: <field name="attachment_ids" widget="many2many_binary" readonly='1'> <tree> <field name="name" default_order="name desc"/> </tree> </field>. But this looks exactly like my original code: <field name="attachment_ids" widget="many2many_binary" readonly='1'/>

Comment: and if I put this: <tree> <field name="attachment_ids" default_order="name desc"/> </tree> no ordering is made as would be required :-(